# LINQ to XML file not saving correctly

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I have a method that removes sync times older than 10 sec's old and then adds a new one when fired:

```
    public void addSyncTime()
    {
        //delete archived sync times
        XMLDocObject.Descendants("LastSync")
           .Where(e => Convert.ToDateTime(e.Element("Time").Value) < DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(-10))
           .Where(e => e.Element("id").Value != "1")
           .Remove();
        string t1 = XMLDocObject.ToString();
        //get the last primary key added
        var lastPrimaryKey = (from i in XMLDocObject.Element("DataLoadTimes").Elements("LastSync").Elements("id")
                              select i).LastOrDefault().Value;
        //increment it once
        int newPrimaryKey = Convert.ToInt32(lastPrimaryKey) + 1;
        //create element to insert
        var newElement = new XElement("LastSync",
               new XElement("id", newPrimaryKey),
               new XElement("Time", DateTime.Now.ToString()));
        //add to XML doc object
        XMLDocObject.Element("DataLoadTimes").Add(newElement);
        string t2 = XMLDocObject.ToString();
    }
```

The above strings are for breakpoint testing.

This above code creates XML like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<!--QTabs Data Storage-->
<DataLoadTimes>
  <LastSync>
    <id>1</id>
    <Time>4/1/2015 10:29:13 AM</Time>
  </LastSync>
  <LastSync>
    <id>2</id>
    <Time>4/1/2015 10:29:14 AM</Time>
  </LastSync>
  <LastSync>
    <id>3</id>
    <Time>4/1/2015 10:29:15 AM</Time>
  </LastSync>
</DataLoadTimes>
```

Here is the save method to save to XML after the above is fired:

```
    public async void saveToXmlFile()
    {
        //storageFile = await storageFolder.GetFileAsync(Settings.xmlFile);
        using (Stream fileStream = await storageFile.OpenStreamForWriteAsync())
        {
            XMLDocObject.Save(fileStream);
        }
    }
```

Now, when using 1st method a few times and saving I am getting a corrupted XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<!--QTabs Data Storage-->
<DataLoadTimes>
  <LastSync>
    <id>1</id>
    <Time>4/1/2015 10:23:53 AM</Time>
  </LastSync>
  <LastSync>
    <id>2</id>
    <Time>4/1/2015 10:27:04 AM</Time>
  </LastSync>
</DataLoadTimes>  <id>3</id>
    <Time>4/1/2015 10:26:43 AM</Time>
  </LastSync>
  <LastSync>
    <id>4</id>
    <Time>4/1/2015 10:26:44 AM</Time>
  </LastSync>
</DataLoadTimes>
```

Note this line: `</DataLoadTimes>  <id>3</id>`

So what's going on here? Debugging shows that the string attempting to be saved stored in the XDocucument object is right:

```
"<!--QTabs Data Storage-->\r\n<DataLoadTimes>\r\n  <LastSync>\r\n    <id>1</id>\r\n    <Time>4/1/2015 10:23:53 AM</Time>\r\n  </LastSync>\r\n  <LastSync>\r\n    <id>2</id>\r\n    <Time>4/1/2015 10:27:04 AM</Time>\r\n  </LastSync>\r\n</DataLoadTimes>"
```

Why is the file getting messed up?

Comment: The file you're saving to is not truncated before you write to it, so you're just overwriting the first part and the rest is what was there before.  You'll need to show us what `storageFile.OpenStreamForWriteAsync()` actually does.

Comment: @Charles Mager How do I truncate the file? storageFile is from Windows.Storage; This is how I initialize: StorageFile storageFile = await storageFolder.GetFileAsync("myxmlfile.xml");

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not too familiar with WinRT, but from the docs I think you need to use:

```
await storageFolder.CreateFileAsync("myxmlfile.xml", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
```

`GetFileAsync` will open the existing file as-is - this would allow you to read it's contents.  As the contents you are writing are smaller than the existing contents, the remaining existing contents are not touched.

If you wanted to stick with `GetFileAsync` then setting `fileStream.Length = 0` before writing should fix the issue you're seeing.